# Can any mediatek android use HotKnot as long as the appropiate files are included in the ROM?

Tags: connection-issues, file-transfer

Where I am currently living, my government has blocked internet access.

We are sending important messages to each other using various mesh network apps like 'firechat', but the problem is, many of my friends don't have these apps installed on their phone and they can't access them from the app store or the internet.

Since I often have to troubleshoot without access to the internet, I like to be prepared for various file delivery methods in case one method doesn't work.

My phone is using a ROM that I have compiled myself and thus I can include functionalities into it that are not normally present on many phones, like FM radio, call recording, IMSI-catcher detection, etc...

#### Could I use HotKnot to send files to another phone if my phone is not a Chinese phone which had HotKnot installed on it originally?

I am wanting to know if it would be worth integrating the HotKnotBeam Service, Share, and Connectivity apks on my mediatek phone's ROM just in case I might need them?

If not, which devices could still use HotKnot even if the service wasn't on the phone originally?

Comment: Can someone add the HotKnot tag please?

Comment: "There is no such  thing as a Hot Knot app, because it’s part of the hardware of the phone." [source](https://blog.chinavasion.com/34848/what-is-hot-knot-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I have edited my question so it was more specific. I was wondering if all mediatek phones could use HotKnot. As I was wondering if I should include these drivers in a new ROM or not.

Comment: @GabrielFair MediaTek is SoC manufacturer. That's no way linked to touch panel.